# want to mention fontsize bigger in .profile file, so that when I open a file using vi / vim editor font become larger

Tags: linux, vi

I want to mention font-size bigger in .profile file, so that when I open a file using vi / vim editor font become larger. What I need to do in .profile ?

Comment: Your font size is generally controlled to `.Xresources`. Vim has little to do with changing the size. However there is limited ability to override the default console font. See [How can I change the font size in gVim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3093/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-in-gvim) (note that is for gvim)

Answer (score 0):

To change the font size, you can use either `xfontset` or `guifontset` depending on your needs.

You should specify this in your vimrc file. it should be at ~/.vimrc